# Remove empty space at bottom of QTableWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I'm using PySide6 6.4.1 to build a table widget that automatically resizes to the number of rows. Here's a minimal example:

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *


class MW(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = QPushButton("Test")

        self.table = QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.setColumnCount(1)
        self.table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)

        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout(self))
        self.layout().addWidget(self.button)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.table)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.test)

        return

    def test(self):
        self.table.insertRow(0)
        self.table.setItem(0, 0, QTableWidgetItem("new item"))

        self.table.adjustSize()
        self.adjustSize()

        return


app = QApplication()

mw = MW()
mw.show()

app.exec()
```

Somehow this always leaves a bit of empty space at the bottom of the table. How do I get rid of this space without doing manual resizing?

[image]

(Nevermind the weird font size, it's a known bug when using UI scaling. I've adjusted the font size manually as well and it doesn't get rid of this problem.)

Comment: Two questions: what should be the height when *no* item exists yet? And what if there are *a lot* of items?

Comment: @musicamante If no items exist, I'd be happy to have only the horizontal header. For many items, I guess the code I posted would run outside of the screen... that's beside the point here though, this is just a mockup. All I want is to know whether there is a way to remove that little extra space at the bottom, or at least how to programmatically determine its height.

Answer (score 0):

Qt item views inherit from QAbstractScrollArea, which has some peculiar size related aspects:

- it has an `Expanding` [*size policy*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) that tells the parent layout it can use as much space as possible, possibly increasing the available space at initialization;
- it has a [`minimumSizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop) that always includes a minimum reasonable size allowing showing the scroll bars (even if they are not visible);
- if the `sizeAdjustPolicy` is `AdjustToContents` it's also based on the viewport size hint;

It's also mandatory to consider a fundamental aspect about scroll areas: size management is a tricky subject, and some level of compromise is necessary most of the times. This is the case whenever the scroll bars potentially change the available size of the viewport (the part of the widget that is able to scroll), which is the default behavior of Qt in most systems, unless the scroll bars are always hidden/visible *or* they are *transient* (they "overlay" above the viewport without affecting its available visible size).

To clarify this aspect, consider a scroll area with content that has a minimum size of 100x100 and scroll bars that have a default extent (width for the vertical one, height for the horizontal) of 20: if the height hint of the content is changed to 110, then you'd *theoretically* need an area of 100x110. But Qt needs to know the hints *before* laying out widgets and setting their geometries. This means that you cannot know if the scroll bars have to be shown *before* the widget is finally laid out, but that hint is required to lay out the widget itself. So, recursion.
Qt layout management is a system that is far from perfect, but I doubt that there is one, at least considering normal UI management (don't consider web layouts: their concept is based on different assumption, most importantly the fact that the whole "window" has potentially infinite dimensions). This is an aspect that **must** be always considered, especially if the shown contents are set to adapt their size based on the contents; it's the case of [`fitInView()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView) of QGraphicsView or the known [issues](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues) of QLayout with rich text based widgets.

Qt doesn't provide "foolproof" solutions for these aspects, because its layout management doesn't allow it as it has been implemented primarily considering performance and *usability*: the UI has to work and be responsive *before* being "fancy".
It's one of the reasons for which it's almost impossible to have real fixed-aspect-ratio widgets or windows. You can work around it, but at some point you'll have some inconsistencies, and you have to live with that. Also consider that this kind of behavior is generally not very UX-friendly. UI elements that resize themselves (and, consequentially, alter the whole layout) at anytime are usually annoying and very user-unfriendly, especially if they displace their or other contents: it's like having a car that constantly moves the driving controls depending on the amount of passengers.

That said, it's not impossible to have a **partially** working solution.

The requirements are to:

- override `minimumSizeHint()`, so that a minimal reasonable size is always returned;
- override `sizeHint()` that is used to *adjust* the widget (and parents) based on the contents of the view;
- change the vertical size policy of the table to `Preferred`, which will tell the layout manager that the height of the size hint will be considered as default, still allowing it to expand in case other items in the layout don't use the remaining space, and eventually shrink it if required;
- eventually do the same for the horizontal policy in order to adapt it to the actual horizontal header size, otherwise use `self.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)`, but be aware that this might complicate things (see the note after the code);

```py
class TableWidget(QTableWidget):
    def sizeHint(self):
        hHeader = self.horizontalHeader()
        vHeader = self.verticalHeader()

        f = self.frameWidth() * 2
        
        # the simple solution is to get the length, but this might be a problem
        # whenever *any* section of the header is set to Stretch
        targetWidth = width = f + hHeader.length()

        # a possible alternative (but still far from perfect):
        width = f
        for c in range(self.columnCount()):
            if hHeader.isSectionHidden(c):
                continue
            width += self.sizeHintForColumn(c)
        targetWidth = width

        if not vHeader.isHidden():
            width += vHeader.width()

        hpol = self.horizontalScrollBarPolicy()
        height = f + vHeader.length() + hHeader.height()
        if (
            hpol != Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff
            and not self.horizontalScrollBar().isHidden()
            and (
                hpol == Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn
                and hHeader.length() + f < targetWidth
            )
        ):
            height += self.horizontalScrollBar().sizeHint().height()
        return QSize(width, height)

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        hint = self.sizeHint()
        minHint = super().minimumSizeHint()
        return QSize(
            min(minHint.width(), hint.width()), 
            min(super().minimumSizeHint().height(), hint.height())
        )


class MW(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        pol = self.table.sizePolicy()
        pol.setVerticalPolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        self.table.setSizePolicy(pol)
```

Be aware that the above doesn't solve all problems. It might work fine for a QTableView having just one column or when using the default interactive (or fixed) section resize mode, but whenever you set different resize modes for each column the result may be wrong.

In order to provide a *finer* resize, you'll need to do much complex computations that take into account each section resize mode for the horizontal header, the default/minimum/maximum and eventually the hint based on the content.

<sup>Further notes: 1. calling `adjustSize()` on the parent is normally enough, it's not necessary to do it on the children; 2. `self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout(self))` is pointless, the `self` argument already sets the layout; just use `layout = QVBoxLayout(self)` and use that as a local variable to add widgets; 3. in Python the `return` at the end of a function is always implicit, you shall not add it as it's useless, redundant and distracting.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. Good point about the redundant `self` in layouting, that crept in at some point, I'll eliminate that.

Comment: As to the returns, I find it visually displeasing to have a function with a "dangling" bottom end as it looks unfinished, so I like to include a return statement to mark the end of the function; to me it's distracting *not* to have it.

Comment: @Antimon You can obviously write in the style you prefer, but keep in mind that the code styling requirements of python already consider that a new indentation block automatically acts as a function end (or return), not to mention the fact that when writing code for/with others (like posting on a website like SO) you have to consider general conventions, not personal habit.

Comment: I gave this a shot, but unfortunately the empty space at the bottom remains. If I print out `minHint`, it turns out to be a constant (71, 71) and doesn't change when adding items. Even though the `minHint` is returned in the overridden method, the widget ends with the height of `sizeHint`.

Comment: @Antimon sorry, I forgot that I was using a different Qt version that behaved differently with size hints. See the update. Be aware, though, that the answer is far from perfect, and it's also possible that a *final and reliable* solution is actually not even possible, due to the way Qt works.

Comment: It seems that this is getting a rather elaborate solution, I'll give it a try when I have time. I also understand your point that this might just not be possible (or at least feasible) in a reliable manner, so maybe I'll just have to live with that space too. Thanks for your help!